What is the MySQL equivalent for SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT
In Postgres, we can lockdown the snapshot of a transaction with SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT statement. It means that several transactions from different connections, if set with the same snapshot, will see the same version of data. This is what I want to do with MySQL.
However, I can't find any equivalent of SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT in MySQL. The closest one seems to be gtid but I'm not sure how exactly i should do with MySQL to achieve the same goal.

MySQL is a much simpler database compared to PostgreSQL. You shouldn't expect it to have all the features that PostgreSQL offers.

Current only Percona version of mysql , have the option
see https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/8.0/start-transaction-with-consistent-snapshot.html
